# Executing a script via key binding?

Tags: iterm

I am trying to create a key binding that will execute a run command instead of "just" inserting the text.

I have set up a Sequence:

- Next Tab
- Send: "run"
- Previous Tab.

The `run` isn't being executed the text "run" is inserted into the next tab before returning to the previous tab.

Is there a way to execute that script?

Comment: Possible duplicates : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote another one : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428912/keyboard-shortcut-to-call-an-applescript-created-with-automator-quick-actio and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/run-an-applescript-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322556/how-can-i-launch-an-applescript-app-im-creating-without-moving-my-mouse

Comment: This is not clear.  Can you [edit] with some details about what script (language) you’re trying to run, where you’re executing this script and what it’s supposed to do?

Comment: @Allan The question is tagged `iterm`, so it seems like they want to do it there.

Comment: @Barmar, is this a Bash/Zsh script?  An AppleScript controlling iTerm?  Javascript?  Is it from within iTerm or expecting to execute outside of iTerm to make it do something?

Comment: It seems like you just need to send the Enter key after sending `run`.

Comment: I use the third-party application FastScripts to connect hot keys to AppleScripts.